# Drag-select on JavaScript (Make elements selectable)

Tags: javascript

How to implement drag-select (make HTML elements selectable by area mouse selecting)?

I'm interested in the element selecting like it is in file explorers (of Windows, Linux) and many other sites that provide a file explorer behaviour (dropbox.com, google.drive, mega.nz, [js-fileexplorer demo](https://cubiclesoft.com/demos/js-fileexplorer/demo.html)).

I mean the selecting when you create a rectangular area by mouse move with all elements are touched by this area are "selected" (for example, an extra CSS class is added to them).

How to do it? Best approach?

Comment: A simple way would be to have a layout where these elements are placed. Then keep track of their position, and on mouseclick, keep track of initial click x,y positions until release. Any elements underneath that area, you would then add a class to.

Comment: Well, keeping coordinates (`getBoundingClientRect`) of each selectable `div` and checking the intersection of the selecting area with them should be OK.

Comment: Please post what you have tried and the one challenge that presents you so we may best assist you here.  Asking for a recommendation is out of scope for this site.

Answer (score 4):

Here is it.

Just keep `{x, y, width, height}` from `getBoundingClientRect` for each selectable item, then check the rectangle intersection of each item with the selecting area in a loop.

*There are 29 lines of code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75902998/11468937) to create the select area rectangle (with only 2 extra lines),
[5 lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13390495/11468937) to check the rectangle intersection,
5 lines to create demo `div`s,
and only 17 lines for the main logic.*

It works fine even with scrolling while selecting.

```js
   
// --- Init ---
for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${Math.random() * 360}, 100%, 50%)`;
  div.classList.add("selectable");
  document.body.append(div);
}

// --- Main ---
const selectables = [];
const selectableElems = [...document.querySelectorAll(".selectable")];
for (const selectable of selectableElems) {
  const {x, y, width, height} = selectable.getBoundingClientRect();
  selectables.push({x: x + window.scrollX, y: y + window.scrollY, width, height, elem: selectable});
  selectable.dataset.info = JSON.stringify({x, y, width, height});
}

function checkSelected(selectAreaElem) {
  const select = selectAreaElem.getBoundingClientRect();
  const {x, y, height, width} = select;
  for (const selectable of selectables) {
    if (checkRectIntersection({x: x + window.scrollX, y: y + window.scrollY, height, width}, selectable)){
      selectable.elem.classList.add("intersected");
    } else {
      selectable.elem.classList.remove("intersected");
    }
  }
}
// ------------

function checkRectIntersection(r1, r2) {    // stackoverflow.com/a/13390495
  return !(r1.x + r1.width  < r2.x ||
           r2.x + r2.width  < r1.x ||
           r1.y + r1.height < r2.y ||
           r2.y + r2.height < r1.y);
}

addEventListener("pointerdown", createSelectAreaDiv);
async function createSelectAreaDiv(event) { // stackoverflow.com/a/75902998
  event.preventDefault();
  const x = event.pageX;
  const y = event.pageY;

  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.position = "absolute";
  div.style.width = "0";
  div.style.height = "0";
  div.style.left = x + "px";
  div.style.top = y + "px";
  div.classList.add("drag-select");
  document.body.append(div);

  function resize(event) {
    const diffX = event.pageX - x;
    const diffY = event.pageY - y;
    div.style.left = diffX < 0 ? x + diffX + "px" : x + "px";
    div.style.top = diffY < 0 ? y + diffY + "px" : y + "px";
    div.style.height = Math.abs(diffY) + "px";
    div.style.width = Math.abs(diffX) + "px";
    checkSelected(div); // extra line 1
  }
  selectables.forEach(item => item.elem.classList.remove("intersected"));  // extra line 2
  addEventListener("pointermove", resize);
  addEventListener("pointerup", () => {
    removeEventListener("pointermove", resize);
    div.remove();
  });
}
```

```css
html, body {
  display: inline-grid;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
div {
  width: 128px;
  height: 32px;
}
.drag-select {
  background-color: rgba(20, 137, 189, 0.5);
}
.intersected {
  border: 5px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this snippet, specially in vanillajs so is easy to have a concrete starting point then you just integrate with whatever framework you are working, thanks again :)

Comment: https://github.com/AlttiRi/drag-select-demo here is the more advanced demo, see the "Features" in readme, although it's 200 lines for total.

Comment: that looks quite interesting, gonna take a look :)   thanks for sharing this :)